# Why is ssh X-Forwarding of browser not working for internal IP addresses?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, sshd, remote-x-session, x11-forwarding

I want to access my private Ubuntu server at home during lunch break at and from work.
The problem was, that at work, the SSH port is blocked by the firewall (default setting).

So I changed the configuration of my ssh server, so that he also listens to port 443 (SSL).

Now I can access my server via ssh alright with `ssh -p 443 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Now I wanted to change the configuration of the router in my local network at home.

so I tried accessing it from the server's browser via x-forwarding:

```
ssh -p 443 -XY xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
user@servername:~#> firefox
```

Like that, I can browse external sites fine, 
but I can't access the server or the router  via their normal IP addresses (10.0.1.1, 10.0.1.2).

Why ?
And how can I change that / what can I do ?

Comment: probably your router connects on port 443 also as it will ask for login and you are already using port 443 for the ssh... try using ssh on another port (not 80 also).

Comment: @laurent: Tried with port 21 (ftp), and same problem there...

Comment: It seems like x-forwarded Firefox/Chrome is using the corporate 10.* instead of the home 10.* IP range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when entering a x-forwarded 10.*.*.*.* IP, Firefox seems to go looking 
for the server in the wrong network (the work network instead of the home network).

The proper way is to establish a ssh tunnel and use FoxyProxy so Firefox uses that tunnel.

```
ssh -C2qTnN -D 8080 username@remote_machine.com
```

FoxyProxy:

```
Select Manual proxy configuration
SOCKS Host: localhost Port: 8080
SOCKS v5
```

That also saves bandwidth and the quality is far better than the one you get using x-forwarding.